# RequireJS doesn't wait for module load?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm struggling with a problem trying to only load the modules my app needs. That list of modules will vary, like below.

This code is inline in a dynamic page:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script>
  //APPROACH #1
  (function(){

     <% foreach(DashBoardItem item in AvailableItems){ %>
          require('js/dashboard/<%= item.Name.ToLower() %>').init(<%= CurrentUser.ID %>);  
     <% } %>

  }());
</script>
```

The idea is to produce something like:

```
<script>
 //APPROACH #1
 (function(){
    require('js/dashboard/sales').init(123);
    require('js/dashboard/inventory').init(123);
    require('js/dashboard/deadlines').init(123);
  }());
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or ho to do it because the above approach causes the error

> Module name "js/dashboard/sales" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I tried generating this instead:

```
<script>
   //APPROACH #2
   require(['js/dashboard/sales', 'js/dashboard/inventory', 'js/dashboard/deadlines' ],
           function(sales, inventory, deadlines){
              sales.init(123);
              inventory.init(123);
              deadlines.init(123);
           });
</script>
```

But this fails because apparently RequireJS won't wait for the modules to load and those three callback parameters (`sales`, `inventory`, `deadlines`) will be `undefined` when it executes.

Am I going about this completely wrong? How can I pass a varying list of required modules from the server side to the client JS?

**UPDATE - fixed**

My problem was that my modules (sales, inventory, deadlines) were incorrectly declared. Thanks to **@anoopelias**'s comment below, I realized that I had used `require(...)` instead of `define(...)` in them. So they were like:

```
//example of WRONG sales.js module
require(['jquery', 'other-module'], function($, otherModule){
  //do stuff, return some object instance
});
```

Once I fixed like below, I could use *APPROACH #2* from above and it worked fine.

```
//example of correct sales.js module
define(['jquery', 'other-module'], function($, otherModule){
  //do stuff, return some object instance
});
```

Comment: Your second approach seems to be fine. Do you have `define` correctly returning an object in all those three modules?

Comment: @anoopelias define does not have to return an object, but in order for a module to work, it does need to be defined. (see [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule) )

Comment: @anoopelias, you're right. I'm still confusing these things here and there. Once I used `define` instead of `require` in each of those dashboard module declarations, the second approach worked. Thanks.

Comment: @sergiopereira I think your first approach also will work if you execute it after loading the modules using second approach somewhere else.

Comment: You should have posted an answer to your question, instead of putting the answer *in* the question. I also made the silly error of using `require` instead of `define`. Thanks.

Comment: @doug65536 I thought it would look a bit opportunistic if I added the correct answer to my own question. I'm glad it helped you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just for the record, for approach #1 you just forgot the [] around the modules:

```
 <% foreach(DashBoardItem item in AvailableItems){ %>
      require(['js/dashboard/<%= item.Name.ToLower() %>']).init(<%= CurrentUser.ID %>);  
 <% } %>
```

unless your js/main hasn't required this modules, requirejs will complain. Even if you include them in your js/main you have to "wait" for main to get finished to load (so nest the foreach in a require call for js/main)